# To make vim delete a file after closing it if its title is "test.cpp"

Tags: vim

As I am currently into CP.
I have to try a variety of code for testing but I am tired of manually deleting every trial code I create. So I want vim to automate this stuff. If the file name is 'test.cpp' and is located at the desktop. It should automatically be deleted so that whenever I open test.cpp a new file is loaded with my predefined template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the kind of things autocommands are made for:

```
augroup TestDotCPP
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimLeavePre /path/to/test.cpp call delete('/path/to/test.cpp')
augroup END
```

That autocommand tells Vim to delete `/path/to/test.cpp` whenever you are quitting Vim while editing that specific file.

See `:help autocommnad` and `:help delete()`.

Comment: The "(SOLVED)" is not necessary and generally considered bad form around here.

Comment: Ok then, Is there any flag to mark that it is solved or no need of doing anything.

Comment: No need to do anything. You accepted the answer so the problem is solved and readers can see it.